# WCF Web.config maxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: wcf

I'm posting a json object with large amount of text.

Below is my current `web.config`. How should I modify to change message size to post large json?

This is urgent, pls reply fast. thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="LogPath" value="\Logs\" />
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10000" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/soap.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_LanguageService"
                contract="TranslatorService.LanguageService" name="BasicHttpBinding_LanguageService" />
        </client>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="webby"  >
                    <webHttp/> 
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_LanguageService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                                maxArrayLength="16384"
                                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                  <security mode="None">
                      <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                          realm="" />
                      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                  </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="AgricultureTradingWebApp.AgricultureWebService.customBinding0" >
                    <binaryMessageEncoding />
                    <httpTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
            multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        <services>
            <service name="AgricultureTradingWebApp.AgricultureWebService">
                <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="AgricultureTradingWebApp.AgricultureWebService.customBinding0"
                      contract="AgricultureTradingWebApp.AgricultureWebService" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <endpoint address="json"
                          binding="webHttpBinding" 
                          contract="AgricultureTradingWebApp.AgricultureWebService"
                behaviorConfiguration="webby"/>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Are you getting them on the client (when receiving the response) or on the server (when sending the request)?

Comment: Error bad request. Message limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using REST, which I haven't done before, so there may be some caveats I'm not aware of.

However, your json endpoint is using the default `webHttpBinding`, which has a MaxReceivedMessageSize of 65536.  Since you want to increase this, you need to define the webHttpBinding that you want to use in your config file, give it a name, and assign that name to the json endpoint's bindingConfiguration attribute:

```
<bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myWebHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                 openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferSize="524288" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="524288"
                 transferMode="Buffered"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength=524288" 
                          maxArrayLength="16384"
                          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The above is a modified version of the basicHttpBinding you defined.  I set an arbitrary value for maxReceivedMessageSize (equal to maxBufferSize and maxBufferPoolSize).  I also increased the maxStringContentLength value in the reader quotas.

In your endpoint, assign the binding above to the bindingConfiguration attribute:

```
<endpoint address="json"
                      binding="webHttpBinding" 
                      bindingConfiguration="myWebHttpBinding"
                      contract="AgricultureTradingWebApp.AgricultureWebService"
            behaviorConfiguration="webby"/>
```

Also, take note of the warning on the MSDN article regarding MaxReceivedMessageSize:

`Increasing this value alone is not sufficient in ASP.NET compatible mode. You should also increase the value of httpRuntime`

[`<webHttpBinding>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412176.aspx)

You'll want to modify the values in my example to suit your needs.

Comment: Actually, it's more like 524288 characters; depending on the encoding used it could be 1 byte per character, but not always.  I view it as bytes as a *general* rule of thumb.